# Scheduled calling function in php

Tags: php, cron

I need to send an email containing which employees are coming late after a specified point in time.

Example:

```
class ControllerName
{
  public function emailSendingAction()
  {
      //Fetching employee details from database
      //code to send an email
   }
}
```

How can I call that function at the specified time?

I googled it and found **crontab**.

How can I call that function using crontab? Or is their any other method?

**Note:** The scheduled time should be fetched from a database column value.

If crontab is best option, then how do I use it?

Comment: `0 10 * * * php /path/to/file.php`.

Comment: you need to write a function in a class to get the value from database and set an ajax call on setinterval in jquery.

Comment: @RolandStarke How i specify call particular action in file and change calling function timing dynamically?

Comment: @MKB I don't know correct time to set time interval. It is stored in database

Comment: Then make another function to get time from database and put in the interval function.

Comment: If i close the application or clear cache, is the set time interval gets reset?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more complicated than you think. Remember it has to send a mail to only those who are not yet present at work. So all employees that come on time would indicate to the database there are present, then the program will select all those who are marked "absent" and then send the mail. I can help you with a code in PHP-MYSQL, HTML, and JQUERY. Will you find it helpful?

Comment: No need to send mail to all absentees employees. Send one mail to head of office reporting that they not come on time